# usage of the words "unknown if not unknowable"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could you please explain the meaning of the words "unknown if not unknowable".

I read online and found this sentence:

> While proving to be a useful framework for rationalising illusions of brightness and the like, a problem with this framework is that the visual experience of individuals (with regard to surface reflectance and illumination) and that of their evolutionary ancestors is **unknown if not unknowable**.

Comment: Please include a link to the source of this passage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means what what they are trying to understand may be unknowable. There may be something that makes that information essentially unavailable.
Even if the information could possibly become known, it is unknown at present.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it with great clarity.